# Unparseable date: "15-03-2013"

Tags: java, date

```
String dateString = request.getParameter("pickerDate"); //dateString "15-03-2013"
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date sdf = null;
try {
    Date date = format.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(format.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting the date from date Picker. But I get an unparsable exception. Any help on how to convert the string "15-03-2013" to store it in the Database as a Date?

Thanks

Comment: Now you are asking how to store the date in a database, which is a completely different question. Please ask that as a separate question. In the meantime I have rolled back your edit which totally broke the formatting and tried to change it into a different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overwriting your first `SimpleDateFormat` with a second one.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

The second one is looking for `MMM`, i.e. a three-character month name. Just delete that second line.

Comment: if I format it, it gets converted into String. but I want to store that in a Date field in DB. Any idea for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to clean up your code.  Try this:

```
    String dateString = "15-03-2013";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

This is replacing the line before - remove this and your code should work.

The line before is a valid format for the what you're passing in:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```